# Having issue with Magento 2 security scan. Magento Compromise Injection

Tags: magento2, security, security-scan-tool, compromise-injection

I have checked with my all the sites with the bundle and merge js I am getting the same issue for all the sites i.e. **Magento Compromise Injection**.

When I remove bundle and merge js then security scan works fine.

It is default Magento having the problem or is there anything that I missed.

How can I resolve this issue **Magento Compromise Injection**?

[image]

Comment: have you ran this test when JS isn't merged to single out the file(s) that may lead to this issue?

Comment: Yes, I have run this without merge but I am not getting an issue with unmerged.

Comment: Now that, _that_ , is a curiosity

Comment: Does magereport.com flag you as infected as well?

Comment: no,  it is not infected.

Comment: Apologies for posting here - don't have the reputation points to comment above. I found the same issue on 2 of my Magento 2.2.3 installations. If bundling is enabled, the scan find malicious javascript. I disabled merging and left bundling and minify enabled, which returned bundle1.min.js as the issue. I ran the site through magereport.com, magescan.com and ran mwscan on the webroot. Nothing found. For now, I've disabled bundling and left minify/merge enabled and Magento's scan returns no issues.